# how could i get the system current date and time in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I don't have much idea about automatic counter,working with date.I need to write a function to set counter for certain date. I have a table with the following structure.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `service_taxdate` (
  `tax` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `end_date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I need to get the system time and set the start date and when I reach end date, I need to insert an alert message. can some one help with code.

Comment: Set the default value for start data.

Comment: system time `<?php echo date('Y-m-d')?>`

Comment: you can also use datetime instead of date.

Comment: you just need to call the date() function of php

Comment: i can display system date but how do i write a counter using this? can u help me code

Answer (score 3):

```
$date = date("y-m-d")
```

would return you the system's date

```
<?php
echo "Today is " . date("Y/m/d") . "<br>";
echo "Today is " . date("Y.m.d") . "<br>";
echo "Today is " . date("Y-m-d") . "<br>";
echo "Today is " . date("l");
?>
```

output:

```
Today is 2015/06/29
Today is 2015.06.29
Today is 2015-06-29
Today is Monday
```

Comment: can i use trigger for making the above code happen automatically

Comment: trigger in what sense? database triggers you mean?

Comment: date("t") returns the total days in a month, if it return 31 means the month has 31 days...you can use this as well.

Comment: cron jobs could be a good option  as well..write down a php script that will be perform some logic and  based on certain scenario would alert you via intermediate entries in the database....run the job every day.

Comment: is there any possible to autolmaticly  get the date and time from system.

Comment: like how? can you explain the scenario?

Comment: i need to get the  start date and end date from the user ,form the start date i need count the date till end date and when it reaches the end date i need to set a reminder like alert action

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('service_taxdate');
$this->db->where('end_date', date('Y-m-d'));
$query = $this->db->get();
// Produces: 
// SELECT * FROM service_taxdate
// WHER end_date =current date ( YYYY-mm-dd)
?>
```

Comment: can i use trigger for making the above code happen automatically

Comment: You can use ajax request to call this function with a timeout of 12 hrs

Comment: `function doAjax() {

  $.ajax({
   ...
   complete: function() {
    setTimeout(doAjax,1000); //now that the request is complete, do it again in 1 second
   }
   ...
  });
}

doAjax(); `

Answer (score 2):

If you want this to happen automatically you can use cron jobs.
Alternatively,

```
SELECT * FROM service_taxdate WHERE end_date = curdate() and datediff(end_date, start_date)=your_counter;
```

To make trigger you have to keep alive system,login everyday and put this code on login or your default controller.

Comment: i need to get the start date and end date from the user ,form the start date i need count the date till end date and when it reaches the end date i need to set a reminder like alert action

Comment: please check edit , used mysql datediff() function to count difference between two date.